# Laravel 4.2: Troubleshooting "Target not instantiable" error

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container, instantiation

I've been stuck on this "Target not instantiable" error for the last 2-3 days and I have no idea why. Someone in the IRC #laravel chat room, yesterday, suggested using `var_dump(App::make('Project\Frontend\Repo\Lead\LeadInterface'))` when in Artisan's tinker interface which I've done and got this response:

```
class Project\Frontend\Repo\Lead\EloquentLead#798 (1) {
  protected $lead =>
  class Lead#809 (21) {
    // bunch of info about the model etc relating to the interface and it's repo class
  }
}
```

One of the members in #laravel pointed out that this meant the interface was instantiated which is great but then I realised this isn't the interface that I'm having a problem with.

So below is how I have things setup. The interface that's apparently not instantiated is ValidableInterface (last portion of code) and running `var_dump(App::make('Project\Backend\Service\Validation\ValidableInterface'))`
returns the dreaded "Target not instantiable" error.

EDIT: `new LeadFormLaravelValidator( $app['validator'] )` extends AbstractLaravelValidator which implements ValidableInterface.

Am I missing some glaring problem with my code?

My service provider

```
<?php namespace Project\Frontend\Service\Form;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Project\Frontend\Service\Form\Lead\LeadForm;
use Project\Frontend\Service\Form\Lead\LeadFormLaravelValidator;

class FormServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

/**
 * Register the binding
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $app = $this->app;

    $app->bind('Project\Frontend\Service\Form\Lead\LeadForm', function($app)
    {
        return new LeadForm(
            new LeadFormLaravelValidator( $app['validator'] ),
            $app->make('Project\Frontend\Repo\Lead\LeadInterface')
        );
    });
}

}
```

My form class

```
<?php namespace Project\Frontend\Service\Form\Lead;

use Project\Backend\Service\Validation\ValidableInterface;
use Project\Frontend\Repo\Lead\LeadInterface;

class LeadForm {

/**
 * Form Data
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $data;

/**
 * Validator
 *
 * @var \Project\Backend\Service\Validation\ValidableInterface
 */
protected $validator;

/**
 * Lead repository
 *
 * @var \Project\Frontend\Repo\Lead\LeadInterface
 */
protected $lead;

public function __construct(ValidableInterface $validator, LeadInterface $lead)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
    $this->lead = $lead;
}
```

My validation rules

```
<?php namespace Project\Frontend\Service\Form\Lead;

use Project\Backend\Service\Validation\AbstractLaravelValidator;

class LeadFormLaravelValidator extends AbstractLaravelValidator {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var Array
 */
protected $rules = array(
    'name'              => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z-\s]+$/',
    'email'             => 'email',
    'cell'              => 'required|numeric|digits_between:10,11',
);

/**
 * Validation messages
 *
 * @var Array
 */
protected $messages = array(
    'regex'                 => 'The :attribute may only contain letters, dashes and spaces.',
    'digits_between'        => 'The :attribute must be 10 numbers long.',
);

}
```

My abstract validator

```
<?php namespace Project\Backend\Service\Validation;

use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;

abstract class AbstractLaravelValidator implements ValidableInterface {

/**
 * Validator
 *
 * @var \Illuminate\Validation\Factory
 */
protected $validator;

/**
 * Validation data key => value array
 *
 * @var Array
 */
protected $data = array();

/**
 * Validation errors
 *
 * @var Array
 */
protected $errors = array();

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var Array
 */
protected $rules = array();

/**
 * Custom validation messages
 *
 * @var Array
 */
protected $messages = array();

public function __construct(Factory $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}

/**
 * Set data to validate
 *
 * @return \Project\Backend\Service\Validation\AbstractLaravelValidator
 */
public function with(array $data)
{
    $this->data = $data;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Validation passes or fails
 *
 * @return Boolean
 */
public function passes()
{
    $validator = $this->validator->make($this->data, $this->rules, $this->messages);

    if( $validator->fails() )
    {
        $this->errors = $validator->messages();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Return errors, if any
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function errors()
{
    return $this->errors;
}

}
```

My validator interface

```
<?php namespace Project\Backend\Service\Validation;

interface ValidableInterface {

/**
 * Add data to validation against
 *
 * @param array
 * @return \Project\Backend\Service\Validation\ValidableInterface  $this
 */
public function with(array $input);

/**
 * Test if validation passes
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function passes();

/**
 * Retrieve validation errors
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function errors();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is `$app->make('Project\Frontend\Repo\Lead\LeadInterface')`. Laravel has no way of knowing what class to instantiate here. You have to tell Laravel by doing:

```
$app->bind('Project\Frontend\Repo\Lead\LeadInterface', 'Your\Implementation\Of\LeadInterface');
```

#### Edit

It's weird that you get that exception since you manually instantiate `LeadForm` and inject the `LeadFormLaravelValidator`. However this should probably resolve the issue:

```
$app->bind('Project\Backend\Service\Validation\ValidableInterface', 
           'Project\Frontend\Service\Form\Lead\LeadFormLaravelValidator');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @lukasgeiter. I'll try out your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: That didn't work. The LeadInterface is instantiated by the way because if you read the first part of my question you'll see it returns data when I do a var_dump(). I'll update the question with this info so it's more clear.

The problem lies with `new LeadFormLaravelValidator( $app['validator'] )`

Comment: I tried a number of things using your suggestion from the edit and none of them worked. The only different error I got was:

"Argument 1 passed to Project\Frontend\Service\Form\Lead\LeadForm::__construct() must be an instance of Project\Backend\Service\Validation\ValidableInterface, null given"

...When I did this...

    return new LeadForm(
                $app->bind('Project\Backend\Service\Validation\ValidableInterface', 
                'Project\Frontend\Service\Form\Lead\LeadFormLaravelValidator'),
                $app->make('Project\Frontend\Repo\Lead\LeadInterface')
            );

Comment: No you're not supposed to do the `$app->bind()` call inside the constructor call. Just before the other `$app->bind()` in your `register()` method.

Comment: I figured that wasn't right on my part. I'll give that a quick test.

Comment: There's just one problem. ValidableInterface is meant to be used for more than one Form class and now that I've bound it to LeadFormLaravelValidator I can't use it in any other validator classes.

Comment: Nevermind. I just tested binding ValidableInterface to another form class (below the code that binds it to LeadFormLaravelValidator) in the same service provider and it works fine.

Comment: Yes it should. As I said, It's kind of weird that Laravel wants to resolve the interface since you manually instantiate the class. Or are you using `$app->make('..\LeadForm')` somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not using it anywhere else. All is peachy ;) Thanks again.